# Can't manage to put data into my database

Tags: sqlite, postgresql, orm, symfony

I am using Symfony 2.0 beta3 and I am facing a rather strange problem. I have
set up the ORM with a sqlite database following the instructions of
the website but when I type:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

then

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

and finally

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I don't get any error (for example last command outputs "Database
schema updated successfully") but nothing is actually inserted into
the database. The table aren't even created. The database file is
generated after the first command but remains empty.

Since I have configured FOS_UserBundle I should have for example a
table fos_user…
When I type

```
 php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

It shows that three SQL requests are pending… If I execute these three requests using
SQLiteManager, it works (so the fos_user table is created)
but when I want to create a user using:

php app/console fos:user:create

I get a "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: fos_user " error.

Why am I not given some error message when I run the first three
commands? Am I missing something?

I face the same behaviour using pdo_pgsql driver, except that the SQL
generated by the dump is not ANSI compliant so it can't be executed
for postgresql (use of datetime and autoincrement instead of timestamp
and serial)….

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [this solution](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=35560) on the Symfony forums.

It would seem the helpers aren't creating two things that you need for the sqlite implementation to work correctly.

Firstly, in the parameters.ini for the project (tweak to suit):

```
 database_path=%kernel.root_dir%/config/MyDatabase.db
```

Secondly, in the config.yml file in the doctrine.dbal section, add the following:

```
 path: %database_path%
```

Then run:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

and it should generate the database for you in the app/config folder.

You will need to run:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

to create the schema. Re-run the code that didn't work and it should work fine.

Comment: `path: %database_path%` that was what I need! BTW, a `schema:create` command creates the database automatically, so you don't need to call `databse:create`

Answer (score 0):

The FOSUserBundle is developed in sync to the symfony master.

1. Be sure to updated both, symfony and the FOSUserBundle.
2. Drop the schema (`php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force`)
3. Manually check the db whether the schema is dropped. Otherwise do it per hand.
4. Clear the cache and ensure that it is writeable.
5. Run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` again.